# Onchange function for stage

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I have two fields in odoo10, and I want to add  `@onchange` function for one of them.

In one field I added three workflows, in first workflow `work1` I added two stages (create, new). Similarly for second `work2` and third `work3`, I added two stages (draft, escalate) and (assign, pending).

When I select `work1` from workflow field then related stages should show in the stage field. So, can anyone solve this problem ?

My python code for that is below :

```
work_flow_stage = fields.Many2one('stage.workflow', string="Work Flow", change_default=True, default=_work_flow_status)
work_stage = fields.Many2one('partner.state', string="Stage")

@api.onchange('work_flow_stage', 'work_stage')
@api.multi
def _work_flow_status(self):
    stage = self.env['stage.workflow'].search([('work_stage', 'in', 'work_flow_stage')], limit=1)
    print "stage", stage
    return stage
```

Comment: Take a look at how it is done in the CRM module. Specifically, look at Leads and how the Stages depend on the Sales Team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method doesn't assign anything to your current work_stage, it just return the value, that would be dismissed after execution.

I am assuming, that you have the same field `work_stage` in your `stage.workflow`.
If you want to do this via `@api.onchange` you could implement it in 2 ways:

```
@api.onchange('work_flow_stage')
def _onchange_work_flow_stage(self):
    return {
        'value': {
            'work_stage': self.work_flow_stage.work_stage.id
        }
    }

    # ========= OR ===========

    self.work_stage = self.work_flow_stage.work_stage.id
```

There might be a possibility to do this with the relation, like:

```
work_flow_stage = fields.Many2one('stage.workflow', 'Work Flow', change_default=True)
work_stage = fields.Many2one('partner.state', 'Stage', related='work_flow_stage.work_stage')
```

Though, I'm not sure would it work when you'll change your work_flow_stage immediately. Please, send the feedback.

Hope, that will help.

Comment: Related field work for me. But above function is not working. For now related field value sufficient for my work. And now i am working on onchange function.